Creating an Azure Stream Analytics Output with Postgresql datasource using az cli in powershell fails
When I try to create an Azure Stream Analytics Output with a Postgresql datasource using az cli in Powershell on an existing stream analytics job and a postgresql database, it fails returning
(BadRequest) The JSON provided in the request body is invalid. The required property 'datasource type' is missing from the request.
Code: BadRequest

Here is the testing powershell code:
$dataSourceJson = @"
{
    "type": "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers/databases",
    "properties": {
        "server": "<YourHostFullName>",
        "database": "<YourDbName>",
        "table": "<YourTableName>",
        "user": "<user>",
        "password": "<password>"
    }
}
"@

# Output to verify the content
Write-Host "Datasource JSON String:"
Write-Host $dataSourceJson

$dataSource = ($dataSourceJson -replace "\s+", "") -replace '"', '\"'

Write-Host "Datasource JSON String on a single line, no spaces and double-quote escaped:"
Write-Host $dataSource

# Create the Azure Stream Analytics output using the datasource
az stream-analytics output create `
    --job-name "<YourJobName>" `
    --name "<YourOutputName>" `
    --resource-group "<YourResourceGroupName>" `
    --datasource "$dataSource" `
    --verbose

You could think that the Postgres output is not supported, but you can create it however into the Azure Portal. It also works using Terraform, eventhough the type of the datasource is missing in the output description afterwards (using az stream-analytics output show).
The datasourceJson string seems to have the right format as when you replace the postgres type "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers/databases" by an Azure SQL type "Microsoft.Sql/Server/Database", it succeeds.
Any clue ?

It looks like a bug in Azure for postgresql datasource type. @Francois Denis

It looks like a bug or limitation with the PostgreSQL server type Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers/databases when using with the Azure CLI. After exploring on this, I found, for all of the SQL servers and databases, the only type of stream analytics output accepts is Microsoft.Sql/Server/Database resource type.
$dataSourceJson = @"
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Sql/Server/Databases",
    "properties": {
        "server": "newserverp.postgres.database.azure.com",
        "database": "newdb",
        "table": "newtable",
        "user": "roots",
        "password": "Jaanu@971204"
    }
}
"@

CLI command:
az stream-analytics output create `
    --job-name "sample" `
    --name "sampleutput" `
    --resource-group "Jahnavi" `
    --datasource "$dataSourceJson" `
    --verbose



Note: If you can see the output in the Azure portal under stream analytics job, it is showing the accurate PostgreSQL server without any conflict.
Meanwhile the issue got fixed by the Microsoft team with the resource type, use alternative workarounds like terraform or Portal as you already mentioned.
